# How to toggle parameters in API call on a fixed INterval in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

for example: I have two values in an array. 
arr = [1,2]

I want api calls in such a way that at time T, I call a function with parameter 1, and at T + 20, with parameter 2, and again after 20 sec, with parameter 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
export default class MyComponent {
    arr = [1, 2];
    paramIndex = 0;
    T = 1000;
    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.toggleParam();
        }, T);
        /// notice that T is integer you should assign at first as example i will set it equal 1 second 
    }

    toggleParam() {
        if(paramIndex == 0)
            paramIndex = 1;
        else 
            paramIndex = 0;
        this.apiCall(arr[paramIndex]);
        setTimeout(()=> {
            this.toggleParam();
        }, 20)
    }

    apiCall(myParam) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay... Cool! I found a way out by using counter and checcking even odd condition as follows:

Comment: this.timerSub = Observable.interval(20000).subscribe(() => {
          const displayCondition = counter % 2;
if (displayCondition === 0) {
..Do Your Code
}
else{..Do Your Code...}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, i found a way out using counters for the above scenario and it goes as follows:

```js
arr=[1,2]
counter = 0
apiCall(){
  this.timerSub = Observable.interval(20000).subscribe(() => {
          const displayCond = counter % 2;
          if (displayCond === 0) {
            // call API using 1st item in array
          }
          else{
            // call API using 2nd item in array
          }
}
```